# PHP post_max_size local value overridden by master value on Plesk / IIS?

Tags: php, iis, plesk

I'm running into a strange issue when uploading large files via PHP (through Drupal, though that's not the issue).

Basically, my file uploads fail due to post_max_size limits being reached, even though the local directive is set to 96M, and the file is 25M.

I've ensured everything else is correct, including `max_input_time`, `max_upload_filesize`, and the IIS FastCGI idle time. All these are plenty large and not the issue.

I am overriding the `post_max_size` directive through Plesk, which (I believe) stores the change in a registry value. Running phpinfo() on the domain shows the correct local and master values for all directives...96M local, 12M master.

The very strange thing is that when I change the master `post_max_size` in php.ini from 12M to 96M (and ensure the change has taken effect), **it works normally!** Changing the master value back to 12M (and keeping a local value of 96M) immediately causes uploads to fail again.

Is this a bug in PHP, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What is the issue? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter key in the 'tags' field to commit a tag, and it submitted the whole thing before I had finished writing the question.

Comment: I cancelled my down vote, but can't cancel the close vote, sorry. I was probably a bit quick off the mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, on Windows, you can only set ini directives that are marked `PHP_INI_USER` per directory. Unfortunately, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are both `PHP_INI_PERDIR`. From the PHP docs at http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

> The settings for the directory would be active for any script running from this directory or any subdirectory of it. The values under the key should have the name of the PHP configuration directive and the string value. PHP constants in the values are not parsed. **However, only configuration values changeable in PHP_INI_USER can be set this way, PHP_INI_PERDIR values can not.**

So even though Plesk has an interface to change those directives, and even though `phpinfo()` picks up on them, *they do nothing to change the actual max upload sizes.* Plesk should not allow you to change those on Windows, and `phpinfo()` should not report the change, but what can you do.

Answer (score 1):

Check PHP's post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini and for any overrides (local php.ini or .htaccess for example)

EDIT: it should be noted that phpinfo() cannot be relied upon for determining if any override will be available during the request (aka when file uploads happen) since it will be processed during the response.

Comment: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` are both overridden (via registry, the only way to do it on Windows) to `96M`, and phpinfo() reflects that fact.

Comment: How are you overriding them then?  Keep in mind that you can't override them using ini_set() in a script that is responding to the HTTP request (because they won't be overridden until it is too late).

Comment: They are being overridden by a registry key. I'm using the Plesk control panel, which has a GUI to change PHP settings per domain, and behind the scenes it writes them to the registry, as that's really the only way to set per domain directives on Windows. `ini_set()` is not used.

Comment: Might be simple, but have you tried restarting services, or simply rebooting with them set to override?

Comment: I haven't restarted the IIS service since this is a busy server, but I've restarted the site's app pool to no avail. Since phpinfo() reports the correct value, I know PHP is picking up on my override...it seems like PHP has a bug in it's upload mechanism that doesn't correctly consult the overridden value when actually receiving a file.

Comment: I personally would suspect that the value is set by, whatever mechanism, after it is too late to matter.  Namely during the response.  But alas I don't have any real IIS experience, only nginx and apache.

Comment: I do think you are right. I'll submit an answer detailing what I found.

Comment: Yeah, you should totally make your own answer and accept it, giving no credit to anyone else.  :(

Comment: Jared, your answer did not sufficiently explain the issue, so I felt a more in depth reply was needed for future searchers. Sorry, wasn't trying to steal any credit, just want the best explanation possible. I see you edited your answer to add more info, but that was after I had already written mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in Plesk. Have you edited any of the templates in Plesk? I know when it runs its cron jobs you can lose certain config edits if you didn't do them via Plesk.

But what about your .htaccess file? You can also set these limits there and that, based on your Plesk config, may the better place to make these changes.

Comment: Have learned the hard way to never change anything outside Plesk! As far as I know, Plesk on Windows with IIS doesn't use .htaccess files, you can only change settings in web.config and the registry, through the Plesk GUI.

Comment: Ah, right IIS. What about the max_file_uploads? If your upload_max_filesize *  max_file_uploads is greater than you memory_limit or post_max_size that could be a problem. Other directives of interest I'd imagine are memory_limit, max_execution_time, max_input_time, upload_max_filesize, max_file_uploads.

Comment: All those related directives are set sufficiently high, I've even modified IIS settings such as FastCGI idle timeout, max request size, etc. Both `post_max_size` and `max_upload_filesize` are set at `96M`, but I'm only uploading 1 `25M` file. It uploads fine when setting the global php.ini directives to `96M`, and fails when you revert them to `12M`.