# PHP Large File Uploads (again)

Tags: iis-7, upload, php, large-files

Firstly sorry for another of the same (countless iterations of this question I know), but I'm completely stoomped on this one and spent all day looking for answers (along with checking all the previous threads here).

So Im trying to upload large(ish) files through PHP. The script fails at files around 8-10Mb mark (works for files upto 7.5Mb, fails at 10Mb). It just returns an empty file array, ie:

```
print_r($_FILES)
= array( )
```

Im running IIS7, using Plesk 10, on a Windows 2008 R2 OS. Heres my form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000000">
  <input name="Filedata" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="button" />
</form>
```

Some relevant php.ini variables:

```
max_execution_time: 240
max_input_time: 360
post_max_size: 1600M
upload_max_filesize: 800M
memory_limit 1600M
```

And my web.config has this in:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="200000000"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I know that the php.ini's are being listened to, because php_info() reports them as that (also ini_get('...') reports them as correct as well. As an aside they are the 'local' values, the 'master' ones are lot lower (but am assuming if php_info() reports the local as that then they are the ones being used). I put in some debug code to my script:

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size') . "<br />";
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . "<br />";
echo $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] . "<br />";
```

That echos out:

```
1600M
800M
10424520
```

The last one is the 10Mb (ish) file size in bytes (I am assuming). So my question is, what am I missing here?

Comment: have you checked your IIS max input/run time?

Comment: Not sure what that is / where I can locate it? I don't think its a time issue though as I upload the 10Mb file in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally found the answer here, and thought it may help some souls in the future.

It turns out that Plesk, although allowing you to overwrite the 'local' php settings, doesn't actually listen to the change, and the 'Master' values in the php.ini are being listened to, and the local ones aren't.

Theres more info here:
[PHP post_max_size local value overridden by master value on Plesk / IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730198/php-post-max-size-local-value-overridden-by-master-value-on-plesk-iis)

To solve, I changed over the master values by changing the default plesk php.ini's as needed. phpinfo() reported my required post_max_size was now 800M in both local and master, and it worked as needed.